# How can I get the size of an Amazon S3 bucket?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, disk-space-utilization, aws-cli

I'd like to graph the size (in bytes, and # of items) of an Amazon S3 bucket and am looking for an efficient way to get the data.

The [s3cmd](http://s3tools.org/s3cmd) tools provide a way to get the total file size using `s3cmd du s3://bucket_name`, but I'm worried about its ability to scale since it looks like it fetches data about every file and calculates its own sum. Since Amazon charges users in GB-Months it seems odd that they don't expose this value directly.

Although [Amazon's REST API](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/latest/index.html?RESTBucketGET.html) returns the number of items in a bucket, [s3cmd](http://s3tools.org/s3cmd) doesn't seem to expose it. I could do `s3cmd ls -r s3://bucket_name | wc -l` but that seems like a hack.

The Ruby [AWS::S3](http://amazon.rubyforge.org) library looked promising, but only provides the # of bucket items, not the total bucket size.

Is anyone aware of any other command line tools or libraries (prefer Perl, PHP, Python, or Ruby) which provide ways of getting this data?

Comment: I wrote a tool for analysing bucket size: https://github.com/EverythingMe/ncdu-s3

Comment: I am astonished that Amazon charge for the space, but don't provide the total size taken up by an S3 bucket simply through the S3 panel.

Comment: For me most of the answers below took quite a long time to retrieve the bucket size, however this python script was way faster than most of the answers - http://www.slsmk.com/getting-the-size-of-an-s3-bucket-using-boto3-for-aws/

Answer (score 220, accepted):

The AWS CLI now supports the `--query` parameter which takes a [JMESPath](https://github.com/boto/jmespath) expressions.

This means you can sum the size values given by `list-objects` using `sum(Contents[].Size)` and count like `length(Contents[])`.

This can be be run using the official AWS CLI as below and was introduced in [Feb 2014](https://aws.amazon.com/releasenotes/CLI/8053677229323004)

```
 aws s3api list-objects --bucket BUCKETNAME --output json --query "[sum(Contents[].Size), length(Contents[])]"
```

Comment: For large buckets (large #files), this is excruciatingly slow. The Python utility s4cmd "du" is lightning fast: `s4cmd du s3://bucket-name`

Comment: That's strange. What is the overall profile of your bucket (shallow and fat / deep and thin)? It looks like ``s3cmd`` should have the same overheads as ``AWS CLI``. In the [code it shows](https://github.com/s3tools/s3cmd/blob/e7fad103ca2e485598f67a787c2789eb460dd9cb/s3cmd#L101-L115) ``s3cmd`` make a request for each directory in a bucket.

Comment: to get it in human readable format:  `aws s3api --profile PROFILE_NAME  list-objects --bucket BUCKET_NAME  --output json --query "[sum(Contents[].Size), length(Contents[])]" | awk  'NR!=2 {print $0;next}  NR==2 {print $0/1024/1024/1024" GB"}'`

Comment: @Rubistro for me the aws cli with `--query` is a lot faster than `s3cmd`, but still this solution is not yet ideal...

Comment: Now that AWS Cloudwatch offers a "BucketSizeBytes" per-bucket metric  this is no longer the right solution.  See Toukakoukan's answer below.

Comment: This just gives me the error: "Illegal token value '(Contents[].Size), length(Contents[])]'"

Comment: @cce depending on usecase the value of BucketSizeBytes may be too stale to be useful. This method produces a more up to date value :)

Comment: @Cerin are your quote marks matching or are you opening with double and closing with single?

Comment: Beware that this only sums the first 1000 objects if a bucket has more.  I highly suggest just using `s3cmd du`, or if you need greater throughput `s4cmd du`.  You can even run them without an argument and it will iterate through all buckets.  It's sort of insane to me that Amazon doesn't provide a way to get at this information more efficiently, but being that's the case why reinvent the wheel?  I think s4cmd is probably as good as you are going to get until Amazon blesses us with a proper solution.

Comment: `s4cmd du` is wonderful, thank you @Brent Faust! small note (for those concerned) that you need to add `-r` to get the sizes of sub-directories as well.

Comment: Illegal token value '(Contents[].Size), length(Contents[])]'

Comment: (on @cce's comment: Toukakoukan user name is now Sam Martin)

Answer (score 497):

This can now be done trivially with just the official AWS command line client:

```
aws s3 ls --summarize --human-readable --recursive s3://bucket-name/
```

Official Documentation: [AWS CLI Command Reference (version 2)](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/ls.html)

This also accepts path prefixes if you don't want to count the entire bucket:

```
aws s3 ls --summarize --human-readable --recursive s3://bucket-name/directory
```

Comment: This is the best and up-to date answer

Comment: Agree, this is the best answer.

Comment: This is very slow for buckets with many files as it basically lists all the objects in the bucket before showing the summary, and in that it is not significantly faster than the @Christopher Hackett's answer - except this one is much more noisy.

Comment: Run on a EC2 instance with the same bucket's region to improve the latency

Comment: If you are only interested in the summary size, this is the fastest and up-to-date solution and you can simply pipe through tail to find that value.

Comment: This can easily take half a day on a large bucket.

Comment: This will show the size of ALL the individual files in the directory tree. What if I just want to total size for the directory?

Comment: Unknown options: --summarize, --human-readable, --recursive

Comment: Works great.  You get a little summary at the bottom.  Not sure about massive buckets, but mine finished the report in about 1 second.  

Total Objects: 3925
Total Size: 3.4 GiB

Comment: Please mind, that it is a lkong operation on huge buckets and consume amazing amount of CPU.

Comment: For large buckets, check out Bahreini's answer.  In the S3 console, go to your bucket > Management > Metrics.  You can view total usage and filter by prefix, tag, etc. https://serverfault.com/a/981112/226067

Comment: this doesnt show the exact file size In bytes

Comment: @NadavB The `--human-readable` option converts sizes from bytes to more "human-brain friendly" values, rounding in the process (for example 36627240 becomes 34.9 MiB). Simply omit that parameter to get the actual byte counts.

Comment: This doesn't work, it lists every item. For some reason --summarize isn't working. And even if it did the point is to AVOID going through every object in the bucket to count its size. The console already allows for that. Like colllin said already, the correct answer is in CloudWatch, either through the S3-Management/Metrics screen or in CloudWatch directly. Counting each object is NOT efficient.

Comment: I would add | tail -2 to avoid flooding.

Comment: This is the best answer and is more unto date with the CLI. Owner of this ticket should update.

Answer (score 186):

### AWS Console:

As of [28th of July 2015](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/amazon-s3-update-delete-notifications-better-filters-bucket-metrics/) you can get this information [via CloudWatch](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/cloudwatch-monitoring.html). If you want a GUI, go to the [CloudWatch console](https://console.aws.amazon.com/cloudwatch/): (Choose Region > ) Metrics > S3

### AWS CLI Command:

This is much quicker than some of the other commands posted here, as it does not query the size of each file individually to calculate the sum.

```
 aws cloudwatch get-metric-statistics --namespace AWS/S3 --start-time 2015-07-15T10:00:00 --end-time 2015-07-31T01:00:00 --period 86400 --statistics Average --region eu-west-1 --metric-name BucketSizeBytes --dimensions Name=BucketName,Value=toukakoukan.com Name=StorageType,Value=StandardStorage
```

**Important**: You must specify both StorageType and BucketName in the dimensions argument otherwise you will get no results. All you need to change is the `--start-date`, `--end-time`, and `Value=toukakoukan.com`.

---

Here's a bash script you can use to avoid having to specify `--start-date` and `--end-time` manually.

```
#!/bin/bash
bucket=$1
region=$2
now=$(date +%s)
aws cloudwatch get-metric-statistics --namespace AWS/S3 --start-time "$(echo "$now - 86400" | bc)" --end-time "$now" --period 86400 --statistics Average --region $region --metric-name BucketSizeBytes --dimensions Name=BucketName,Value="$bucket" Name=StorageType,Value=StandardStorage
```

Comment: Or in [the CloudWatch console](https://console.aws.amazon.com/cloudwatch/): (Choose Region > ) Metrics > S3

Comment: This is by far the easiest and fastest solution. Unfortunately the answer is still only in fourth place.

Comment: This worked for my bucket with 10million+ objects. But the bash script didn't return anything, had to go to the GUI).

Comment: It should also be noted that you'll have to change the region as well

Comment: may 2018: the script errors with `Invalid value ('1525354418') for param timestamp:StartTime of type timestamp`

Comment: How I can add filters created in metrics tab of above aws cli command? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/user-guide/configure-metrics-filter.html

Comment: Note also the [restrictions on period](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/cloudwatch/get-metric-statistics.html): 
- Start time between 3 hours and 15 days ago - Use a multiple of 60 seconds (1 minute).
- Start time between 15 and 63 days ago - Use a multiple of 300 seconds (5 minutes).
- Start time greater than 63 days ago - Use a multiple of 3600 seconds (1 hour).

Comment: @RamratanGupta, use the --query option (see [filters](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/controlling-output.html#controlling-output-filter)), eg: `--query "Datapoints[*].[Average]`

Comment: Also be wary of `Name=StorageType,Value=StandardStorage`: if your bucket has some custom lifecycle (utilizing Inrequent Access Storage Class, for example), replace `StandardStorage` with `StandardIAStorage` or some other value (see [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/cloudwatch-monitoring.html#s3-cloudwatch-metrics) for details.

Comment: You need to grant the IAM user the `CloudWatchFullAccess` permission to see this. (Can anyone recommend a more restrictive permission group that permits `cloudwatch:GetMetricStatistics`?)

Comment: This answer needs an update. You can access the same cloudwatch information directly from the Metrics Tab in the S3 console now, graph and everything.

Comment: It should be noted that the number displayed in the Metrics tab is either an estimate, or buggy because you won't get the exact count. I verified multiple times by downloading everything from the S3 bucket and comparing the number of local objects to remote, and it was always off by 1 or 2. Even if you wait for some time, and the bucket is not used at all, it doesn't seem to get updated properly.

Comment: I'm wondering how quickly this updates. My use-case is to count the number of objects uploaded to an s3 bucket in a pipeline. I suspect CW won't be fast enough.

Answer (score 109):

[s3cmd](http://s3tools.org/s3cmd) can do this :

`s3cmd du s3://bucket-name`

Comment: Thanks.  Here's some timing.  On a bucket that holds an s3ql deduplicated filesystem with about a million files using about 33 GB of undupicated data, and about 93000 s3 objects, s3cmd du took about 4 minutes to compute the answer.  I'm curious to know how that compares with other approaches like the php one described elsewhere here.

Comment: It is slow because the [S3 ListObjects API call](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ListingKeysUsingAPIs.html) returns objects in pages of 1000 objects. As I/O is by far the limiting factor I think any solution will be relatively slow over 93000 objects.

Comment: [s4cmd](https://github.com/bloomreach/s4cmd) can also do the same thing, with the added benefit of multi-threading the requests to S3's API to compute the result faster. The tool hasn't been updated recently, but the Internet passer-by may find it useful.

Comment: s4cmd just returns 0 for me, and returns `BotoClientError: Bucket names cannot contain upper-case characters when using either the sub-domain or virtual hosting calling format.` for buckets with uppercase characters.

Answer (score 30):

If you want to get the size from AWS Console:

1. Go to S3 and select the bucket
2. Click on "Metrics" tab

[image]

By default you should see *Total bucket size* metrics on the top

Comment: In the graph, I saw nothing. Only when I hovered my mouse over the graph did I see dots appear that told me the daily total.

Answer (score 26):

If you download a [usage report](https://portal.aws.amazon.com/gp/aws/developer/account?ie=UTF8&action=usage-report), you can graph the daily values for the `TimedStorage-ByteHrs` field.

If you want that number in GiB, just divide by `1024 * 1024 * 1024 * 24` (that's GiB-hours for a 24-hour cycle). If you want the number in bytes, just divide by 24 and graph away.

Answer (score 24):

Using the official AWS s3 command line tools:

```
aws s3 ls s3://bucket/folder --recursive | awk 'BEGIN {total=0}{total+=$3}END{print total/1024/1024" MB"}'
```

This is a better command, just add the following 3 parameters `--summarize --human-readable --recursive` after `aws s3 ls`. `--summarize` is not required though gives a nice touch on the total size.

```
aws s3 ls s3://bucket/folder --summarize --human-readable --recursive
```

Comment: Provide the link to where amazon actually states this please.  I can't find it.

Comment: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/index.html

Comment: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/ls.html is a better link

Comment: This answer worked the best and fastest for me.

Comment: best and fastest answer!

Answer (score 16):

s4cmd is the fastest way I've found (a command-line utility written in Python):

```
pip install s4cmd
```

Now to calculate the entire bucket size using multiple threads:

```
s4cmd du -r s3://bucket-name
```

Comment: No, `s4cmd du s3://123123drink` will not simply return the size of the bucket. To get the size of the bucket you do add the recursive `-r`, like this: s4cmd du -r s3://123123drink

Comment: Yes, good point @BukLau (added `-r` to example above to avoid confusion when people are using simulated folders on S3).

Comment: What if we want versions also to be considered in the calculation for versioned buckets?

Answer (score 9):

You can use the s3cmd utility, e.g.:

```
s3cmd du -H s3://Mybucket
97G      s3://Mybucket/
```

Comment: how do we we go about using this if we have to use something like aws --profile saml s3 xyz and so on

Answer (score 6):

So trolling around through the API and playing some same queries, S3 will produce the entire contents of a bucket in one request and it doesn't need to descend into directories.  The results then just requiring summing through the various XML elements, and not repeated calls.    I don't have a sample bucket that has thousands of items so I don't know how well it will scale, but it seems reasonably simple.

Comment: This does seem to be the best option. Will update this post in the future if it scales poorly and I need to do something else.

The library that ended up providing easy access to the raw API results was this PHP one: http://undesigned.org.za/2007/10/22/amazon-s3-php-class

Comment: Isn't that only limited to the first 1000 items?

Answer (score 6):

I used the [S3 REST/Curl API](http://undesigned.org.za/2007/10/22/amazon-s3-php-class) listed earlier in this thread and did this:

```
<?php
if (!class_exists('S3')) require_once 'S3.php';

// Instantiate the class
$s3 = new S3('accessKeyId', 'secretAccessKey');
S3::$useSSL = false;

// List your buckets:
echo "S3::listBuckets(): ";
echo '<pre>' . print_r($s3->listBuckets(), 1). '</pre>';

$totalSize = 0;
$objects = $s3->getBucket('name-of-your-bucket');
foreach ($objects as $name => $val) {
    // If you want to get the size of a particular directory, you can do
    // only that.
    // if (strpos($name, 'directory/sub-directory') !== false)
    $totalSize += $val['size'];
}

echo ($totalSize / 1024 / 1024 / 1024) . ' GB';
?>
```

Answer (score 4):

... A bit late but, the best way I found is by using the reports in the AWS portal.
I made a PHP class for downloading and parsing the reports.
With it you can get total number of objects for each bucket, total size in GB or byte hrs and more.

Check it out and let me know if was helpful

[AmazonTools](http://amazontools.blogspot.com/2009/12/first-alpha-release.html)

Comment: This is an interesting solution, although a little hackish. Worried about it breaking if/when Amazon changes their site, but I may have to try this out once I have enough objects that the other way becomes too slow.

Another benefit of this approach is that you don't get charged for any API calls.

Comment: . . . its an assumption but, if Amazon do change the look of their site, I doubt they would change the back end much, meaning the current GET and POST queries should work. I will maintain the class in the event it does break anyway as I use it often.

Comment: @Corey its not working http://undesigned.org.za/2007/10/22/amazon-s3-php-class

Answer (score 4):

I recommend using S3 Usage Report for **large buckets**, see [my How To](http://blog.nuxi.pl/2015/aws-tip-of-the-day-get-s3-disk-usage-per-bucket.html) on how to get it
Basically you need to download Usage Report for S3 service for the last day with Timed Storage -  Byte Hrs and parse it to get disk usage.

```
cat report.csv | awk -F, '{printf "%.2f GB %s %s \n", $7/(1024**3 )/24, $4, $2}' | sort -n
```

Answer (score 4):

The AWS documentation tells you how to do it:

```
aws s3 ls s3://bucketnanme --recursive --human-readable --summarize
```

This is the output you get:

```
2016-05-17 00:28:14    0 Bytes folder/
2016-05-17 00:30:57    4.7 KiB folder/file.jpg
2016-05-17 00:31:00  108.9 KiB folder/file.png
2016-05-17 00:31:03   43.2 KiB folder/file.jpg
2016-05-17 00:31:08  158.6 KiB folder/file.jpg
2016-05-17 00:31:12   70.6 KiB folder/file.png
2016-05-17 00:43:50   64.1 KiB folder/folder/folder/folder/file.jpg

Total Objects: 7

   Total Size: 450.1 KiB
```

Answer (score 2):

For a really low-tech approach: use an S3 client that can calculate the size for you. I'm using Panic's Transmit, click on a bucket, do "Get Info" and click the "Calculate"-button. I'm not sure how fast or accurate it is in relation to other methods, but it seems to give back the size I had expected it to be.

Answer (score 2):

Since there are so many answers, I figured I'd pitch in with my own. I wrote my implementation in C# using LINQPad. Copy, paste, and enter in the access key, secret key, region endpoint, and bucket name you want to query. Also, make sure to add the AWSSDK nuget package.

Testing against one of my buckets, it gave me a count of 128075 and a size of 70.6GB. I know that is 99.9999% accurate, so I'm good with the result.

```
void Main() {
    var s3Client = new AmazonS3Client("accessKey", "secretKey", RegionEndpoint.???);
    var stop = false;
    var objectsCount = 0;
    var objectsSize = 0L;
    var nextMarker = string.Empty;

    while (!stop) {
        var response = s3Client.ListObjects(new ListObjectsRequest {
            BucketName = "",
            Marker = nextMarker
        });

        objectsCount += response.S3Objects.Count;
        objectsSize += response.S3Objects.Sum(
            o =>
                o.Size);
        nextMarker = response.NextMarker;
        stop = response.S3Objects.Count < 1000;
    }

    new {
        Count = objectsCount,
        Size = objectsSize.BytesToString()
    }.Dump();
}

static class Int64Extensions {
    public static string BytesToString(
        this long byteCount) {
        if (byteCount == 0) {
            return "0B";
        }

        var suffix = new string[] { "B", "KB", "MB", "GB", "TB", "PB", "EB" };
        var longBytes = Math.Abs(byteCount);
        var place = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Floor(Math.Log(longBytes, 1024)));
        var number = Math.Round(longBytes / Math.Pow(1024, place), 1);

        return string.Format("{0}{1}", Math.Sign(byteCount) * number, suffix[place]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an older question but here is a PowerShell example:

`Get-S3Object -BucketName <buckename> | select key, size | foreach {$A += $_.size}`

`$A` contains the size of the bucket, and there is a keyname parameter if you just want the size of a specific folder in a bucket.

Comment: First run the Get-object..line and then run $A (for those not familiar with PowerShell)

Answer (score 1):

To check all buckets size try this bash script

```
s3list=`aws s3 ls | awk  '{print $3}'`
for s3dir in $s3list
do
    echo $s3dir
    aws s3 ls "s3://$s3dir"  --recursive --human-readable --summarize | grep "Total Size"
done
```

Comment: This worked great.

Comment: Capturing the output in a variable just so you can loop over it is a wasteful antipattern.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `s3cmd`:

```
s3cmd du s3://Mybucket -H
```

or

```
s3cmd du s3://Mybucket --human-readable
```

It gives the total objects and the size of the bucket in a very readable form.

Comment: Does `du` traverse list all the objects or retrieve the metadata?  Would really like an api version of the reports version or what is displayed in the aws console...

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a Bash script, s3-du.sh that will list files in bucket with s3ls, and print count of files, and sizes like

```
s3-du.sh testbucket.jonzobrist.com
149 files in bucket testbucket.jonzobrist.com
11760850920 B
11485205 KB
11216 MB
10 GB
```

Full script:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ “${1}” ]
then
NUM=0
COUNT=0
for N in `s3ls ${1} | awk ‘{print $11}’ | grep [0-9]`
do
NUM=`expr $NUM + $N`
((COUNT++))
done
KB=`expr ${NUM} / 1024`
MB=`expr ${NUM} / 1048576`
GB=`expr ${NUM} / 1073741824`
echo “${COUNT} files in bucket ${1}”
echo “${NUM} B”
echo “${KB} KB”
echo “${MB} MB”
echo “${GB} GB”
else
echo “Usage : ${0} s3-bucket”
exit 1
fi
```

It does do subdirectory size, as Amazon returns the directory name and the size of all of it's contents.

Answer (score 0):

Also [Hanzo S3 Tools](http://code.google.com/p/hanzo-s3-tools/) does this.  Once installed, you can do:

```
s3ls -s -H bucketname
```

But I believe this is also summed on the client side and not retrieved through the AWS API.

Answer (score 0):

Hey there is a metdata search tool for AWS S3 at https://s3search.p3-labs.com/.This tool gives statstics about objects in a bucket with search on metadata.

Answer (score 0):

By [Cloudberry](http://www.cloudberrylab.com/) program is also possible to list the size of the bucket, amount of folders and total files, clicking "properties" right on top of the bucket.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use the command-line, on Windows and OSX, there's a general purpose remote file management app called [Cyberduck](https://cyberduck.io/). Log into S3 with your access/secret key pair, right-click on the directory, click `Calculate`.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me..

```
aws s3 ls s3://bucket/folder/ --recursive | awk '{sz+=$3} END {print sz/1024/1024 "MB"}'
```

Comment: Can you add a few more details ?

Comment: This is essentially the same solution as [another answer](http://serverfault.com/a/684975/218924) posted about a year earlier.

Answer (score 0):

CloudWatch has a default S3 service dashboard now which lists it in a graph called "Bucket Size Bytes Average". I think [this link will work](https://us-west-1.console.aws.amazon.com/cloudwatch/home?region=us-west-1#cw:dashboard=S3) for anyone already logged into AWS Console:

Answer (score -1):

Following way uses AWS PHP SDK to get the total size of the bucket.

```
// make sure that you are using correct region (where the bucket is) to get new Amazon S3 client
$client = \Aws\S3\S3Client::factory(array('region' => $region));

// check if bucket exists
if (!$client->doesBucketExist($bucket, $accept403 = true)) {
    return false;
}
// get bucket objects
$objects = $client->getBucket(array('Bucket' => $bucket));

$total_size_bytes = 0;
$contents = $objects['Contents'];

// iterate through all contents to get total size
foreach ($contents as $key => $value) {
   $total_bytes += $value['Size'];
}
$total_size_gb = $total_size_bytes / 1024 / 1024 / 1024;
```