# Amazon S3 Console: How to find total number of files with in a folder?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

So I can see S3 console and can get into my folder with files listing but I don't find way to find total number of files in it other than going thru pagination which does not work considering thousands of files.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I get the size of an Amazon S3 bucket?](https://serverfault.com/questions/84815/how-can-i-get-the-size-of-an-amazon-s3-bucket)

Answer (score 20):

This will list your objects, and in the end you'll see Total objects count, and size:

```
aws s3 ls s3://bucketName/path/ --recursive --summarize
```

just change bucketName with your bucket name and path is actually a folder within a bucket, if you need that as well (or remove it if you want the whole bucket)

you can also use s3api from cli:

```
aws s3api list-objects --bucket bucketName --query "[length(Contents[])]"
```

As noted in comment, can take a while in case of a large bucket.

Comment: I'd just note that this may take a while on a large bucket.

Answer (score 8):

if you just need the number of files without actually printing the files you can pipe what [@Caldazer](https://serverfault.com/users/475421/caldazar) proposed to `wc -l` like

```sh
aws s3 ls s3://bucketName/path/ | wc -l
```

Answer (score 7):

This is easy to do in the new S3 console directly.

As shown here, select the S3 bucket, and then select the folder of interest. Next, click the `Actions` button and select `Get total size` as shown here:

[image: get total size of selected folder]

Then you should get a popup showing you the number of objects in the folder and the calculated size like so:

[image: size results]

Comment: Simple and Clean!

Comment: If you have more than 300 files in a given path this is not a valid solution as it remains static above that

Answer (score 3):

Another way to grab just the number of objects in your bucket is to `grep` for "Total Objects", which is part of the output automatically displayed when using `--summarize`:

`aws s3 ls s3://bucketName/path/ --recursive --summarize | grep "Total Objects:"`

For a folder with 1633 files, this will return:

`Total Objects: 1633`